# MongoDB aggregation with match and group not working

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where the following query

```
db.getCollection('abc').find( {"uuid" : { "$in" : ["08AAACP2626A1ZZ","23AAACP2626A1Z7","27AAACP2626A1ZZ"] }}, {field1:1})
```

returns:

```
42000  
8000  
0  
0
0  
8000  
42000
```

. I am trying to obtain the sum of all these values using

```
db.abc.aggregate([ { $match: {"uuid" : { "$in" : ["08AAACP2626A1ZZ","23AAACP2626A1Z7","27AAACP2626A1ZZ"] } } }, { $group: { _id : null, total : { $sum: "$field1" }} } ]);`
```

which results in **total** equal to zero. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you show your documents? Maybe you have `iGSTAmount` as string.

Comment: @Ashh Oh yes.. its a String field. How do I convert it to integer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the field is String, you can use `$toInt`

```
{$group: {
  _id: null,
  sum: {
    $sum: {
      $toInt:"$field1"
    }
  }
}}
```